# neo4j rest API not working

Tags: java, rest, neo4j

having problems with the neo4j java-rest-binding API

```
git clone https://github.com/neo4j/java-rest-binding
mvn clean package
```

Then got my JAR.

Tried this:

```
import org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestAPI;
import org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestAPIFacade;
import org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.entity.RestNode;
import org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.query.RestCypherQueryEngine;
import org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.util.QueryResult;
import static org.neo4j.helpers.collection.MapUtil.map;

import java.util.Map;

public class Connect {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("starting test");
        RestAPI api = new RestAPIFacade("http://localhost:7474/");
        System.out.println("API created");
        final RestCypherQueryEngine engine = new RestCypherQueryEngine(api);
        System.out.println("engine created");

        QueryResult<Map<String,Object>> result = engine.query("start n=node({id}) return n", map("id",1));

        System.out.println("query created");
        System.out.println(result);


    for (Map<String, Object> row : result) {
        Object tagline = row.get("tagline");
        long id=((Number)row.get("id")).longValue();
        System.out.println("id is " + id);
        System.out.println(row.get("myRow"));
        }
   }
}
```

Added the neo4j rest and embedded libraries and got this error message.  (BTW I have checked and there is a node 1 and the server is running locally)

starting test

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/core/Response$StatusType
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestAPIFacade.<init>(RestAPIFacade.java:294)
at Connect.main(Connect.java:20)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.core.Response$StatusType
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
... 7 more
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably have a bunch of jars to include as dependencies. 
Including the rest binding as a maven dependency would of course take care of it:

org.neo4j
    neo4j-rest-graphdb
    1.8.1

If you've built from source, then I usually do the unscientific thing of looking at the pom.xml https://github.com/neo4j/java-rest-binding/blob/master/pom.xml and picking out dependencies from /target/dependencies

Answer (score 1):

You can use in the src build

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
```

which will put all dependencies into

```
ls target/dependency
```